# Content Organizer Rule Creation Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using the Content Organizer feature to move documents of a specific content type into a specific folder in a document library in the same site.  I created a content organizaer rule with a property setting that uses the property testcolumn.  Testcolumn is a site column defined as a lookup to column on a custom List, testlist, and then added to a site content type.  The items in this list are displayed in the Value dropdown list and I can select the specific value I want to use for this rule.

[image: property settings]

The problem is that I can create and save rules provided that there are no more than 19 items in the testlist list.  When I have 20 items in the testlist, it looks like the rule was saved by the UI.  If I open the rule and go to edit it, the Value for the testcolumn property is (None).  If I look at the item in powershell, the Value property is equal to '0' and not the ID of the item I saved in the UI.  If I delete a record in the testlist so that the total number of items drops below 20, I can save the rule without issue.  I have tried different combinaitions of items in the list in case it was a text issue, but when I have 20 items or more in the list, the rule is not saved.

I have looked at the ULS logs and it states the "Routing Engine: UpdateRule() has successfully updated the rule, rule.Name=TestRule1" when I save the rule.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is partially listed [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/04/06/setting-sharepoint-drop-down-lists-w-jquery---20-items.aspx).  Looks like the page renders the control differently if the number of items is 20 or greater.  The content organizer rule creation page does not handle this change and does not show any error when saving the information.

I was able to get around this limitation in the UI by adding the rules through code during my feature creation event.  A link to creating rules through code is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.ecmdocumentrouterrule.aspx#CommunityContent).